# Cannot debug web worker in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am using Angular 8, and I am using web workers.
I created web worker according to angular standard documentation https://angular.io/guide/web-worker.

I have problem to debug my code into the web worker. In Firefox debugging works perfectly but in chrome I cannot set break point to any line of the my code. Chrome version is:  83.0.4103.

When ever I want to put breakpoints to the code I wrote in the web worker it automatically jump to the line:

```
module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "1.worker.js"
```

After it I see that breakpoints is here, but code never stop at that line, sometimes even console log does not work.

Image below show how breakpoints are there but debugger never stops.

[image]

Is there any trick here which I do not get it ?

Comment: In my case it stops at the breakpoint but not highlight it sometimes..My chrome version is  83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit).I switched to chrome canary for now to debug the workers.

Comment: I just have checked opera, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when debugging and had to downgrade to version 81, and I still can't find a solution for higher versions

Comment: Use opera, the same engine and it works like a charm :)